# more hits vs most hits

Tags: difference

Does it make any difference whether I use *more* or *most* in this sentence?

> Whoever of the two of you makes **more/most** hits in the last round,
>   wins the whole game.

Comment: You can *optionally* include the definite article before ***most***, but not before ***more***. But all three permutations are perfectly natural, and effectively mean the same thing in your context. Note that you *don't* want that comma after ***round***, and it's normally ***whichever** of the two* (more idiomatically, ***whichever of you [two]***), not ***whoever***.

Answer (score 1):

> Whoever of the two of you makes more hits in the last round, wins the whole game.

or

> Whoever of the two of you makes the most hits in the last round, wins the whole game.

Comment: Prefer 'whichever of the two of you'.